# При получении данных из БД вместо кириллицы получаю u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0435

Tags: php, mysql, json, unity3d

Запрос  идет через  PHP. Скрипт Get PHP:

```
<?php
  include 'db.php';
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM `Opora`
                        ORDER BY `Opora`.`Record` DESC
                        LIMIT 0 , 10");
  $rows = array();                
  while (($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query))) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
  echo json_encode ($rows);
?>
```

Проблема скорее  всего в том что все собираю в JSON
При обращении  на страницу  http://cyberpunch.host/1/get.php
Вся кириллица из Базы  Данных  отображается в таком виде u0410\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0439"
Подскажите как мне это  исправить не убирая  преобразование в  JSON?
Заранее Благодарю.

Comment: `.decode()` ???

Comment: Это на тему... Стоит парень на трассе у своей машины, которая сломалась.. Читает мануал.. Проходит мимо знающий человек и говорит "Трещетка с башкой на 19"  И что бы  это значило??? .Это потом уже многим позже стало ясно, что трещетка это такой авто ключ, а башка 19 это насадка на этот ключ и надо было открутить болт, под правым колесом и верхним пыльником  за  рулевой рейкой под сайлентблоком с правой стороны  рядом  с передним рычагом...:)))))   ..  Так же  и  тут.. Вопрос задан ответ......  .decode()   :))))

Comment: @timur `php` != `python`

Comment: Скрипт PHP на cервере.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191383/php-decode-encoded-string

Comment: Благодарю вас, но мне кажется  это не совсем то... По крайней мере у меня не получилось реализовать их схему. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но там речь идет о string  а у меня array  да еще и в JSON.. Хотя мои знания  в PHP Ничтожны...

Comment: Ну, ладно, сейчас какой-нибудь пэхэпэшник придет и вам ответит. А то у вас на пэхэпэ знания нечтожны, а я вообще пхп не знаю -- пишу на питоне ;)

Comment: Похоже нет спецов в этом вопросе...

Answer (score 1):

В итоге решил.Мало ли кому пригодится.
echo json_encode ($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ---  Не кодировать многобайтовые символы Unicode (по умолчанию они кодируются как \uXXXX). Доступно с PHP 5.4.0.